# Horizontal scrollbar on mobile screen

Tags: html, css

When I view my web page on desktop/larger screen, there is no horizontal scroll bar, but when I view the page on smaller/mobile screen a horizontal bar appears. I don't want that horizontal bar to appear on any screen. Could you guys help me out on this matter, and point me to the problems in my code?
[Link to the web page](https://codepen.io/testube/pen/VBmewj)

```
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
  }

html,
body {
      height: 100%;
      font-size: 100%;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     }
```

for the full code please follow the provided link.

Any help will be highly appreciable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me explain the issue, in your codepen link https://codepen.io/testube/full/VBmewj/, you are showing the `quote` using css `left: 56rem` in the class `cite`. that is bad way of  getting the result, you can set `right: 0` instead or do it as shown below

instead of:

```
cite {
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  left: 56rem;
}
```

use

```
cite {
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
}
```

i tested it on your codepen, it works fine. :)

Comment: Actually, I'm new to web development, self-learning through books and online resources. Though, the problem was actually solved with suggestion from @Girish, I've learned new things from both of them. Thanks guys.

Comment: glad to help, always try to fix the issue, don't add hacks to resolve it for now.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you may add mediaquery code

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
cite {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;

}
}
```